# How to prove that the uniform limit of $C^k$ functions is $C^{k-1,1}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, regularity

Already asked in SE but no response, I think it also reasonably belongs here.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829428/uniform-convergence-of-ck-functions

Basically what the title says, plus the important hypotheses that the functions are uniformly bounded in $C^k$. If not the limit should just be Lipschitz.

Properly written:

Let $f_n : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that $\|f_n\|_{C^k(\Omega)} \leq C$. Assume that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly. Then, $f \in C^{k-1,1}(\Omega)$.

I expect the limit (up to subsequences) to be in $C^{k-1,1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the uniform limit"?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I meant the functions converge uniformly to a limit.

Comment: Let's assume $f_n\in C^k(I)$ for a closed interval $I$. If you mean *uniformly bounded in the norm of C^k(I)*, i.e., $\sup\{|f_n^{(k)}(x)|: x\in I, n\in\mathbb N\}<\infty$, then the sequence is relatively compact in $C^{k-1}(I)$ by Arzela-Ascoli and the uniform limit stays in $C^{k-1}(I)$. Anyway, this is not really research level.

Comment: Agree, that's the easy part. Now I would like to see that the limit belongs to $C^{k-1,1}$. Maybe it's also a one-liner and I'm being dense here.

Comment: By Arzela-Ascoli you find that every subsequence of $f_n$ has a further subsubsequence that converges in $C^{k-1}$, and hence in $C$. Uniqueness of the limit in $C$ says that $f$ is also the $C^{k-1}$ limit of the subsubsequences. The "every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges" construction implies that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C^{k-1}$. Then just close with $f^{(k-1)}(x) - f^{(k-1)}(y) = \lim f_n^{(k-1)}(x) - f_n^{(k-1)}(y)$ which shows that $f^{(k-1)}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: What is exactly the definition of $C^{k-1,1}(\Omega)$ here? There is possibly a subtlety if $\Omega$ is not convex; then $\|Df\|_{\infty, \Omega}\le K$ does not imply that $f$ is  $K$-Lipschitz: it is true only locally. So if  $C^{k-1,1}(\Omega)$ means "derivatives of order $k-1$ are Lipschitz" , then it could be false even for a constant sequence $f_n=f$